# JdbcTemplate insert XmlType failed on larger sizes

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbctemplate, xmltype

I can't insert quite big XML to Oracle XMLType column using JDBC driver and Spring JdbcTemplate.

String isn't small, so I create `CLOB` and pass it to `XMLTYPE(?)` in insert command:

```
String insertSql = "INSERT INTO tab (xmlcol) VALUES (XMLTYPE(?))";
int[] types = new int[] {Types.CLOB};
SqlLobValue xmlLob = new SqlLobValue(xmlString);
Object[] params = new Object[] {xmlLob};
int status = jdbcTemplate.update(insertSql, params, types);
```

Everything is OK when `xmlString` is small - for example `2 KB`, but when it's bigger (for example `450 KB`) `SQLException` exception occurs with this message:

```
ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

How insert big XML document to XMLType column?

*Details:*
I'm using Database Oracle 12.1, Spring 4.3, ojdbc7 12.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create XMLType in Java code and then add to `PreparedStatement` parameters,

There's an example of [Uploading XML into XMLTYPE column in database with Spring JDBCTemplate](https://www.mdrsolutions.com/uploading-xml-into-xmltype-column-in-database-with-spring-jdbctemplate/):

> ```
> //Next, we have to wrap the byte array in an InputStream to accepted
> InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(t.getObject().getBytes());
>
> //Then, instantiate an XMLType object by using native OracleConnection and InputStream of the byte array object
> final XMLType xmldoc = new XMLType(conn, is);
> ...
> ps.setObject(3, xmldoc);
> ```

**EDIT - solution details:**

Add dependencies to `pom.xml` which provide :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>xdb6</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlparserv2</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Extract and unwrap normal `Connection` object to `OracleConnection` and use it to create `XMLType` as described in article linked above. There is also no need to create prepared statement it can be executed by `jdbcTemplate`:

```
String xmlDocument = "<xml>...<very_large>...</xml>"
XMLType xmlType = new XMLType(conn, xmlDocument);
int status = jdbcTemplate.update(insertSql, xmlType);
```

Now it must work with XML content above `4 KB` (`1 MB` tested) size or even larger.